# Select Query takes more excution Time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have **850k** Records in a Table" keywords".
 i want search values using Like

```
 SELECT keywords FROM tbl_keywords WHERE keywords LIKE '%%bio medical%%'.
```

I am working in local Xampp server. Normally it takes **3Sec**.
 After some research create an **index** for the table and changed the **InnoDB** into **MyISAM**.Now its takes 1.7sec.

---

But i wanna search with **"10k"** keywords.so its takes too long time. any other method for getting quick result in MySQL

Comment: you can use full-text indexing but that is only for `sql`. As far I know there is not faster way then indexing in `mysqli`

Comment: better use [`LIMIT`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) for faster approach .if some  one need more record you can change limit accordingly .its ***like pagination approach*** .At the time you need full count of matching record use same query with `COUNT`

Comment: Use ElasticSearch, man

Comment: I am trying with **full-text index**  and using **MATCH, AGAINST** Method. `SELECT keywords FROM tbl_keywords WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('%bio medical%')`.Now I am getting result in **0.007SEC**. But in this method, it get all of the records which have **"medical"**.i need which has exactly **"Bio Medical"**.

Comment: Perhaps use `match` + `like`. F.e. [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140050/153574)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a full text index, if that is what you need.

However, when creating the index you need to be careful and understand a bit about what your are doing.  Two key concepts are:

- stop words
- minimum word length

The stop words are words that are automatically removed.  You have some control over there.  The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) is here.

The second is the minimum word length.  By default, 3 character words may be ignored.  You can learn about that [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length).

Changing either of these requires rebuilding the index.